# How to configure Pushwoosh from java code for android application

Tags: java, android, push-notification, pushwoosh

Please help to understand how to configure application for send notification using pushwoosh.

My current task - create notification mechanism for android mechanism:

my progress:

1. I register on http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-gcm-api-configuration/ and made steps according this instructions:http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-gcm-api-configuration/

Result - I get parameter value with name "API Key"

2.I am reading this java code example:

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-JavaSample

this code uses strange constants:

```
 public static final String PUSHWOOSH_SERVICE_BASE_URL = "https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/";
 private static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
 private static final String APPLICATION_CODE = "PW_APPLICATION_CODE";
```

I don't know where can I get it.please clarify.

**P.S.** I don't work with android before. Please correct my step successively if I wrong.

Comment: refer to http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-gcm-api-configuration/

Comment: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/ for native android integration.

Answer (score 4):

For native android integration [refer to](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/)

where PW_APPID – Pushwoosh Application ID, PW_PROJECT_ID – Project Number you receive from Google GCM, Project ID is a number but make sure you prefix it with the letter “A”

Comment: Thus I should to write code in android application?

Comment: If you write that in AndroidManifest.xml please prefix Project ID with the letter "A". The reason for that is the number is too long for Android to get from Manifest (Android will try to get integer and the number is int64) and there is no way to get it as String :(. If you write Project ID in the code (.java file) you don't have to prefix it.

Comment: Is PW_APPID result of this steps http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-gcm-api-configuration/ ?

Comment: PW_PROJECT_ID – Project Number you receive from Google GCM. Can you provide concrete steps?

Comment: No the project no at the end pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/…  is PW_PROJECT_ID.

Comment: PW_APPID – Pushwoosh Application Code/ID (usually in 8C1C4-66H1E format )is the app-id that you receive from pushWoosh console after registering your project on https://cp.pushwoosh.com/